# Automatically fill foreign key row

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I'm trying to create a login/register system for a project using laravel, and since it's my first time, I've been running into a lot of troubles, so I'd ask to please forgive me for any extremely dumb mistakes I've made.

I've already succesfully added a new custom field to the default registration screen, but in my modified users table, I also have two foreign keys referencing other tables ('gameInfo_id' refers to the 'gameInfo' table, and 'role_id' refers to the 'roles' table)

This is the error I'm getting:
[image: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails]

Does this mean I have to find a way for the foreign key to be filled in automatically? If so, how would I go about doing this?
I've done some googling and found that this usually seems to be issue, but I've never found a clear solution.

Thank you!

Here's my migrations in the users table:

```
      Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('firstName');
        $table->string('lastName');
        $table->string('email')->unique;
        $table->string('password');
        $table->integer('gameInfo_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('role_id')->unsigned();
        $table->timestamps();
    });

    Schema::table('users', function($table) {
        $table->foreign('gameInfo_id')->references('id')->on('gameInfo');
        $table->foreign('role_id')->references('id')->on('roles');
    });
```

gameInfo is a table of scores that the user would achieve in a game we're also making. What I'm trying to make happen is, when a new user registers an account, it creates a new row in gameInfo, to which the gameInfo_id foreign key would refer. The columns of this newly created row could be set to 0 by default if it helps

Comment: Your error simply means that the value you give for "gameInfo_id" or "role_id" does not exist in their referenced tables.

Comment: Do you have any data in the gameInfo table at all?

Comment: @Shadow none yet, no, gameInfo is a table of scores that the user would achieve in a game we're also making. What I'm trying to make happen is, when a new user registers an account, it creates a new row in gameInfo, to which the gameInfo_id foreign key would refer. The columns of this newly created row could be set to 0 by default if it helps

Comment: No, it should no be set to 0, it should be set to null. I'm not an expert on Laravel. Does the `$table->integer('gameInfo_id')->unsigned();` code generate a nullable field with no default value?

Comment: Yep, that it does

Comment: Are you sure it creates a nullable field? Don't you have to add `->nullable()` to the field definition for that?

Comment: @Jesse how can you be sure it creates a nullable value if your insert is broken? :) @Shadow is right, you need to add `->nullable()` to the foreign key. If however your usecase is that those fields should not be empty for any user, @Philipp's answer is correct.

Comment: @Robert based on the error message, it is the insert that brings out the error message, not the definition of the foreign key. Therefore I do not think that the existing values in the users table are an issue. I believe that `$table->integer('gameInfo_id')->unsigned();` creates a not null integer field with no default value (that in itself a bad practice). Since in the insert no value is defined for gameinfo_id, it will default to 0. Since the gameinfo table is empty, this violates the foreign key. To me it seems that atm the only solution is to define the field as nullable (not null)

Comment: @Shadow I never said the definition causes the error,  it is his first user insert... the error simply means that whatever if he tries to insert (0) does not exist in the other table

Comment: Thanks for your answers. When I opened the table in HeidiSQL, the "not null" box was always unticked by default, so I made my assumptions. I'll add the ->nullable argument for sure, I'll let you know how it turns out :)

Answer (score 1):

I would do it the other way around. 
I would reference the user on the gameInfo table with a user_id column.
that way, the user hasMany gameInfo, and a gameInfo belongs to a user. Since the Game info isn't created before the user is created, and has played a game.

Does that make sense?

Comment: Makes sense to me :) I'm first going to try some of the options given to me in the comments, and I'll probably implement your suggestion as well after that, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If the users table already contains datasets, where some of them don't have existing `gameInfo_id` or `role_id`, you can't add an foreign key constraint to the table.
The table must be in an valid state, before you add an foreign key constraint.

That means: Adding an new foreign key constraint to an existing field is not the best idea. Doing it anyway, you have to fix the integrity before.

If your still on an development environment, the best way to fix this would be to start all over again with `migrate:refresh`.
If the system runs in production with users, you have to fix all users with invalid or unset `gameInfo_id` and `role_id`. If you have just a few users, you could do this by hand. If you have many users, you could do some magic inside the migration script (iterate over all users and add missing references, before you add fk constraints).

Answer (score 0):

Since the ->nullable() didn't seem te be recognized by laravel, I instead decided to give each column in gameInfo a default value of 0, which works just fine for me as well.

On the other hand, reversing the FK relationship between users and gameInfo also worked, so my problem's been resolved!

Thank you all very much for your answers, every contribution is appreciated greatly!